# Ant Propertyregex part of file path

Tags: java, regex, for-loop, ant, ant-contrib

I am looping list of files inside base directory using for of Ant-Contrib library. I want to get the part of file path after base directory but without filename.

For example my base Directory is : C:\projects\Dev\Main\Sample Game\js
I have lot of js scripts and inside this folder and subfolders name like

```
C:\projects\Dev\Main\Sample Game\js\simple\welcome\ss.js
C:\projects\Dev\Main\Sample Game\js\hard\welcome\cc.js
C:\projects\Dev\Main\Sample Game\js\easy\welcome\ee.js
```

I want to get only `\simple\welcome\`. I am using the below code.

http://pastebin.com/TpqXBb27

```
<for param="filename">
    <path id="project.fileset">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/js" includes="/*">
            <include name="**/*.js" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <sequential>
        <basename property="file.@{filename}" file="@{filename}"/>
        <propertyregex property="currentdirectory" 
            input="@{filename}"
            regexp="${basedir}/js//([^//]*)//${file.@{filename}}" 
            select="\1"
            casesensitive="false"
            override="true" />
        <echo message="FullPath:@{filename}" />
        <echo message="Directory:${currentdirectory}" />
    </sequential>
</for>
```

I don't know what regex I should provide there... I tried with regex `${basedir}/js//([^//]*)//${file.@{filename}}`, but getting the below error

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 3
C:\projects\Dev\Main\Sample Game\js\simple\welcome\ss.js
```

Please give some suggestion for this regex

Comment: i see no regexp related task in your snippet, it just pulls the basename. However the regex .+\\js(.+\\\) will catch \simple\welcome\ as group 1 from C:\projects\Dev\Main\Sample Game\js\simple\welcome\ss.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like more of a job for `pathconvert` rather than `propertyregex`

```
<for param="filename">
    <path id="project.fileset">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/js" includes="/*">
            <include name="**/*.js" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <sequential>
        <basename property="file.@{filename}" file="@{filename}"/>
        <!-- dirname strips off the trailing file name, leaving the full dir -->
        <dirname property="dir.@{filename}" file="@{filename}"/>
        <pathconvert property="currentdirectory.@{filename}">
            <file file="${dir.@{filename}}" />
            <!-- pathconvert strips off the leading ${basedir}/js -->
            <map from="${basedir}/js" to="" />
        </pathconvert>
        <echo message="FullPath:@{filename}" />
        <echo message="Directory:${currentdirectory.@{filename}}" />
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are on a PC, and when you use `${basedir}`, it's giving you the `${basedir}` with backward Windows slashes for directory separators. The `<fileset/>` is doing the same.

I ran into this very same situation, and I had to first do a `regexreplace` on my path, then do my substitution. Here's the code directly from my project:

```
            <var name="dest.name"               unset="true"/>
            <var name="file.lastmodified"       unset="true"/>
            <var name="file.type"               unset="true"/>

            <file.mdate file="@{file}"
            property="file.lastmodified"/>

            <propertyregex property="file"
            input="@{file}"
            regexp="\\"
            replace="/"
            override="true"
            defaultvalue="@{file}"/>

            <propertyregex property="dest.name"
            input="${file}"
            regexp="^${fileset}/"
            replace=""
            override="true"/>
```

Note that I now have to use `<var/>` to unset the properties, so I can use them over and over in my `<for>` loop:

The first `regexreplace` will change

```
C:\projects\Dev\Main\Sample Game\js\simple\welcome\ss.js
```

to

```
C:/projects/Dev/Main/Sample Game/js/simple/welcome/ss.js
```

From there, you can use  the `basedir` task to remove the script. Then, you just need to for the `/js/` directory.

```
 <regexreplace property="currentdirectory"
    file="@{file}"
    regex=".*/js/(.*)"
    select="\1"
    override="true"/>
```